# WPF Datepicker text isn`t changed according to binding when user clear date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datepicker

I have datepicker on my window and want to achieve simple behaviour: when user clear datepicker's text set datepicker date to Today

XAML:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateFrom}" Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0"></DatePicker>
```

ViewModel DateFrom property:

```
public DateTime? DateFrom
{
  get { return dateFrom; }
  set
  {
    if (dateFrom == value) return;
    dateFrom = value ?? DateTime.Today;
    OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

But I encounter weird behaviour if user clear today date from datepicker - on UI datepicker stays empty, but in ViewModel I have `DateFrom == DateTime.Today`. If user clear any other date all works as expected, only scenario with Today Date fails.

Is this datepicker issue or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateFrom, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
  Width="150" Margin="0,20,0,0"></DatePicker>
```

The value of `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `PropertyChanged` by default. But when you clear today's date, the property is not changing.

So, you have to change the value of `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus`. In that case the property is updated every time `DatePicker` loses focus.

Comment: Can't believe that i overlooked this solution. Thank you, work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Internally it checks previous and current values, and raises property changed only if they are different. I suppose it's `pickerAutomationPeer.RaiseValuePropertyChangedEvent(oldValue, newValue);` if you dig into `OnSelectedDateChanged` code inside DatePicker.

The easiest way to avoid that is to make values always different by using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Yes, I believe date binding works like this by default. I was thinking about using`DateTime.Now` as workaround, but @ra2or solution works for me